# How to get TOAD to split package file on open?

Tags: toad

Somehow my TOAD version-12.8.0.49 setting changed and it no longer splits my Oracle package file on open.

From the `F1` Toad Manual:

> Save the file. Close the file and open it again. Toad will ask you if
>   you want to split the file. Select Yes. Now the package body and the
>   package spec are in separate tabs in the Editor. In addition, the
>   comments at the beginning of the code specify that each tab is a "Toad
>   Chunk" of one file.

I've tried that, but it doesn't work. Instead,file opens into one window.

Any suggestions on how to get TOAD to split package into separtate views (spec and body)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place a `/` between the **SPEC** and the **BODY**.
2. Configure **VIEW**, **TOAD OPTIONS**, **OPEN/SAVE** to either `Automatic` or `Prompt`.

[image]